# Unique key only in array of subschemas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schemas. One of its keys takes the type of an array of schemas.

```
let instanceSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }
})

let mainSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    instances: { type: [instanceSchema], required: true }
})
```

So the `mainSchema` has a key that is an array of `instanceSchemas`. I want the behavior to be such that I can have `instanceSchemas` with the same name if they are members of different `mainSchemas`, like so:

```
let MainModel = mongoose.model("MainModel", mainSchema);

// Succeeds
main1 = new MainModel({
    "instances": [ {"name": "Instance1"}, {"name": "Instance2"} ];
});

// Succeeds
main2 = new MainModel({
    "instances": [ {"name": "Instance1"}, {"name": "Instance2"} ];
});
```

As shown, we have two named "Instance1" and two named "Instance2" but they are members of different documents (main1 and main2) so my target behavior is that this should be allowed. However, using `unique` prevents this from happening as Mongoose checks all `instanceSchema` models. Is there a way to allow duplicates as long as they are members of different documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, unique doesn't work like that.

When you tag a field unique in a mongoose schema, it will create a unique index on that field in MongoDB.

MongoDB index entries are made per-document, not per array entry.

For example, if you have an index on `{field :1}` and  insert the document  `{field:["a","b","a","b","c","d"]}`, then the entries in that index for this document will be:

```
"a" 
"b" 
"c" 
"d"
```

In MongoDB, when an index is created with the `unique: true` option, it enforce that any value only appears once #*in the index*#.  This means that the above document would be perfectly acceptable even if the index on `{field: 1}` were unique.

To quickly demonstrate this, I used your model defined above, and executed:

```
    res1 = await (new MainModel({instances:[{name:"1"},{name:"2"},{name:"1"}]})).save();
    console.log("Inserted: ",JSON.stringify(res1));
    res2 = await MainModel.collection.getIndexes({full: true});
    console.log("Indexes: ",JSON.stringify(res2));
    res3 = await (new MainModel({instances:[{name:"3"},{name:"2"},{name:"4"}]})).save();
    console.log("Inserted: ",JSON.stringify(res3));
```

This logged:

```
Inserted:  {"_id":"60d273060ffb1ac8e48359e5","instances":[{"_id":"60d273060ffb1ac8e48359e6","name":"1"},{"_id":"60d273060ffb1ac8e48359e7","name":"2"},{"_id":"60d273060ffb1ac8e48359e8","name":"1"}],"__v":0}
Indexes:  [{"v":2,"key":{"_id":1},"name":"_id_"},{"v":2,"unique":true,"key":{"instances.name":1},"name":"instances.name_1","background":true}]
/Users/joe/temp/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/error.js:57
    return new MongoError(options);
           ^

MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.mainmodels index: instances.name_1 dup key: { instances.name: "2" }
    at Function.create 
... snip ... {
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { 'instances.name': 1 },
  keyValue: { 'instances.name': '2' }
}
```

As you can see, it create a unique index on `{ 'instances.name': 1 }`, permitted duplicate entries within a single document, and prohibited an identical entry in the other document.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I was hoping for a quick and clever solution but it looks like the only way to get the behavior I wanted is to code validation manually.