# How to set unique index in MongoDB (unique index is not working in MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, express

Here I am creating a review on a tour I want that one single user can post only one review but it is not working . my question is how to achieve that one user can post only one review..

reviewSchema.index({ tour: 1, user: -1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true })

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*? Any exception message?

Comment: actually I wanted to prevent duplicate reviews but it is not preventing , with this code It should work, it should create a unique index in the data base so that one user can review one tour once,

Comment: no exception message

Comment: Did you try without "sparse :true" - which is anyway not recommended any more

Comment: This question seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68089203/unique-key-only-in-array-of-subschemas